# Would the following code causing problems in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I saw someone writing code like this , in a C++ class:

```
int foo ( int dummy ) 
{
   this->dummy = dummy;
}
```

Shall we use code like that , will it cause problems ?

I tried to compile something like this , it seems to be worked.

@update:
I posted this mostly about the name `dummy` ,  and the internal variable `this->dummy` , and if it's problem causing

Comment: Why wouldn't that be ok?

Comment: Why would this be causing problems? This is an usual setter. But IMHO, I would create this method as `void` since it does not return a thing.

Comment: @WagnerVaz , please see my `@update` , i cared about other things more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's perfectly fine for a member function, other than you're missing a `return` statement. `dummy` will shadow the member variable and so you use `this->` to refer to member.

```
int foo ( int dummy ) 
{
   this->dummy = dummy; // set member to argument
   return this->dummy;
}
```

Don't do this for things more complex than a simple set function, as it's confusing.

```
int foo ( int dummy )  // Bad practise! Rename this param as the function isn't a setter
{
   this->dummy = dummy * 2 + 1; 
   return this->dummy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with doing that perse.  It can get confusing though if you use dummy assuming it is coming from the class but its actually coming from the parameter.

IMO, its better to use something to denote it is a class member.  Some people use simply mDummy, other m_Dummy, others just write dummy_.

Its up to you what you prefer but most of all you should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not fine. The function is defined as returning an `int` but there is no `return` statement. The compiler might only give a warning about this, but the function calling `foo` might expect it to return a valid value, which it doesn't, and bad stuff might happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way if you're passing a parameter with the same name as the member variable.
But it might be a better practice to avoid a hidden (member-)variable by using different names. There's different coding styles, some would use dummy_, some would use mDummy or other ways to name member variables. This makes your code less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is nothing wrong with your use, but the code needs to return an int as its an int function :)

Dummy variable in your current class is assigned to the passed int, however do remember they are different but now pointing to the same thing, therefore its better to give it a different name as its in a different.

You could however loose precision under certain variable types.

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct intlist {
  int size;
  int i[1];
} intlist;

intlist *
makeintlist (int size)
{
  intlist *ilp = malloc (offsetof (intlist, i[size])); /* not C++ */
  ilp->size = size;
  return ilp;
}
```

member variable size is allocated to size

Answer (score -1):

1. That will work.
2. Don't do it, it's confusing!